# Spring annotation component

Tags: java, spring, annotations, components, code-injection

I'm having some problems understanding how to use annotations, especially with beans.

I have one component

```
@Component
public class CommonJMSProducer
```

And I want to use it in another class and i thought I could do that to have a unique object

```
public class ArjelMessageSenderThread extends Thread {
    @Inject
    CommonJMSProducer commonJMSProducer;
```

but commonJMSProducer is null.

In my appContext.xml I have this :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.carnot.amm" />
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you create instances of `ArjelMessageSenderThread`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure Spring to use this autowiring feature:

`<context:annotation-config/>`

You can find the details of annotation-based config [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html).

`ArjelMessageSenderThread` also have to be managed by Spring otherwise it won't tamper with its members since it does not know about it.

**OR**

if you cannot make it a managed bean then you can do something like this:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ...
ArjelMessageSenderThread someBeanNotCreatedBySpring = ...
ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(
    someBeanNotCreatedBySpring,
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_AUTODETECT, true);
```

**OR**

as others pointed out you can use annotations to use dependency injection on objects which are not created by Spring with the [@Configurable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) annotation.

Comment: `component-scan` includes `annotation-config`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create instances of `ArjelMessageSenderThread`.

If `ArjelMessageSenderThread` is a bean that should be created by spring you just have to add `@Component` (and make sure the package is picked up by the component scan).

However, since you extend `Thread`, I don't think this should be a standard Spring bean. If you create instances of `ArjelMessageSenderThread` yourself by using `new` you should add the `@Configurable` annotation to `ArjelMessageSenderThread`. With `@Configurable` dependencies will be injected even if the instance is not created by Spring. See the [documentation of @Configurable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) for more details and make sure you enabled [load time weaving](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Answer (score 0):

I used XML instead of annotations. This seemed difficult for not a big thing. Currently, I just have this more in the xml

```
<bean id="jmsFactoryCoffre" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg name="brokerURL" type="java.lang.String"
        value="${brokerURL-coffre}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplateCoffre" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref local="jmsFactoryCoffre" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="commonJMSProducer"
    class="com.carnot.CommonJMSProducer">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplateCoffre" />
</bean>
```

And another class to get the bean

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

Thanks anyway